# Why some files return Network Error: 410 Gone on Firebug for C# web application under IIS?

Tags: networking, iis-7, firebug, c#-2.0

this is kind of tricky: I have an C# web application running always on http://localhost (it is configured like this in csproj properties).

The site runs fine on VS 2008, but Firefox plugin called Firebug is showing this messages:

[image: network error 410 gone]

The files exist on the folders, but IIS has some trouble when trying to show them.

What can I do to solve this issue?

My environment: IIS 7, Windows 7, Visual Studio 2008, Firefox 3.6. Classic Application pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved when bypassing Proxy configuration for localhost :-/